# Django model admin hooks order

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to find the model admin hooks ordering for a request, I need to inject a LogEntry into an inline model and I am tring to find the correct hook points for addition, modified and delete actions on the form.

I know that the log will be created under the modelAdmin in which the inline sits but I need to add one.

Is there any documenttation on the modelAdmin hook paths ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the ModelAdmin hooks you can use:

`ModelAdmin.save_model(request, obj, form, change)` - This method is called after the ModelAdmin form is submitted and validated. You can use this hook to modify the object instance before it is saved to the database.

`ModelAdmin.delete_model(request, obj)` - This method is called when an object is deleted from the ModelAdmin. You can use this hook to perform additional actions when an object is deleted, such as logging the deletion.

You can find more information on ModelAdmin hooks in the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: Hey Thanks, these do not exist for the inlineModelAdmin, what i guess would be really handy is to find where the LogEntry is injected into a normal Model admin and an inline model admin